# how to add two paragraphs using iText one next to other

Tags: java, netbeans, itext

I want to create a PDF document using iText and in that I want to add a paragraph next to another paragraph (Left and Right). I tried to merge two paragraphs by adding those two to another paragraph. But it didn't work for me. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use chunk to do this task.
like

```
chunk c = new chunk("this is first paragraph",font);
chunk c1 = new chunk("this is second paragraph",font2);

paragraph p1 = new paragraph;

p1.add(new chunk(c1));
p1.add(new chunk(c2));

documnet.add(p1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's possible to use a table? This example gives a 5 column table

```
PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(5);

int headerwidths[] = {12, 22, 22, 22, 22};
try {
    t.setWidths(headerwidths);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

t.setWidthPercentage(100);

t.addCell(borderlessCell("text", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, fBold));
t.addCell(borderlessCell("text", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, fBold));
t.addCell(borderlessCell("text", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, fBold));
t.addCell(borderlessCell("text", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, fBold));
t.addCell(borderlessCell("text", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, fBold));
```